# Issues with cell reuse in a UITableView custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

In my my app I have used a custom cell. Within it I have many fields like button, image, textfield, label.

Among those I need to display the `indexpath.section` and `indexpath.row` values

I tried with

```
cell.sectionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];    
cell.rowLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];
```

but the displayed values are some time wrong due to reuse mechanism.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Also specify whether this is all in code or you are using IB or storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can share some other code.

In the meantime (that's the traditional way)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //dequeue the cell here...

    if(!cell) {
        //create the cell here...
    }

    cell.sectionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];
    cell.rowLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]; // set row here

    return cell;
}
```